# SQL Always-ON Availability group (consists of 4 nodes ) session gets data loss

Tags: sql-server, transactions, data-loss

In my company, we have **SQL Always-ON Availability group (which consists of 4 nodes )** for a solution.

The problem is, when we conduct 5/10 million row updates on one cluster node (SQL Always-ON Availability) and during the job, turn off the node VM (for testing purposes), Service shifts to the alternate node automatically but the active (row update process) session gets data loss.

Microsoft already replied on this issue that:

> this is the expected behavior for AGs
> At failover, the SQL Server interrupts all existing connections, and thus also all "in-flight" transactions, even with manual failover.

My concern is, how can we mitigate this issue so that transactions like PIN reset, ticket raise, or any other critical transactions are not impacted if any unexpected scenario(deadlocks, full logfile, timeouts, VM down etc.) happened.

How can we manage this from the application or database?

Comment: Are you using synchronous or asynchronous replication? If async you *must* change to synchronous and ensure all databases show as *synchronized*  before manually failing over.

Comment: using synchronous.
Case: Conduct 5 million row updates on 1 cluster node (SQL Always-ON Availability - consists of 4 nodes ), during the job, turn off the VM.
Expectation: Operation will continue without data loss from the new active node (SQL Always-ON Availability - consists of 4 nodes )
Issue: Service shifts to the alternate node (SQL Always-ON Availability - consists of 4 nodes )but the active (row update process) session gets data loss.

Comment: When you say "conduct 5 million row updates", that operation is committed on the primary server? That is, it's not something like `begin tran; update 5m rows; failover;`, right? If you perform the same experiment w/o shutting off the primary instance, what does the log send queue look like? How long does it take to drain?